# Change logo for each user in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am stuck somewhere as i could not find any solutions like i have a query
can we change the logo for each user in joomla back-end ?

Or Any other CMS, can you suggest which contains this type of facility.I Need to show the different 2 logo for each other who has been registered on my website (administrator would do that)

Any Suggestion would be very thankful.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I dont think any CMS default provide this...you have core for it...or may be you can create a joomla module providing such functionality...

Comment: Joomla Plugin Could be the best among all ?

Comment: Fine, I am waiting for more best responses, may b someone did the same job what i am asking would b the better for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific logo for each user, i.e. unique to each user, you can use a combination of CSS/PHP and save the images to a certain folder.

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
?>
/* This needs to reference the element you are changing */
#logo{
      background: url(/blah/images/<?php echo $user->id; ?>-logo.png);
}
</style>
```

Or you can simply swap the reference to the img if it is using an image rather than a background image.

```
<img src="/blah/<?php echo $user->id; ?>-logo.png"/>
```

I wasn't sure what version of Joomla, or which logo you were replacing so I could not be more specific.
You could even take it one step further and check that the image/file exists first using

```
if(file_exists('path-to-blah/<?php echo $user->id; ?>-logo.png'))
...
```